# Javascript search objects by text

Tags: javascript, typescript

How would I write a generic function in javascript which would search on array of objects  get me result .

For example let's say I have an array of objects.

```
var arr= [
   {a: 1011, b: "abc"}, 
   {a: 2012, b: "abd"}, 
   {a: 2013, b: "cbde"}, 
   {a: 2014, b: "xyz"}
];
```

Search(arr,"101") would return below array

```
 [{a: 1011, b: "abc"}]
```

and Search(arr,"bd") would return below array

```
[{a: 2012, b: "abd"}, 
 {a: 2013, b: "cbde"}]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const search = "ab";

arr.filter(e => {
   const entries = Object.entries(e);
   return entries.some( entry =>
   entry[0].toString().includes(search) || entry[1].toString().includes(search))

})
```

I haven't checked it, but should be close to what you're after.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, this is what I was looking for ..Only thing is entry.key and entry.value does not work on chrome , I had to do entry[1]

Comment: Okay, I did it from memory, faulty as it is.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Jeff for your answer . Solution using Jeff's answer .

```
function filter(data,txt ) {
  return data.filter(e => {
     const entries = Object.entries(e);
     return entries.some(entry=>entry[1]?entry[1].toString().includes(txt):false);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you might find an object by property and value.

You can use this function:

```
function findObjectByText(arr, property, value) {
  var result = arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x[property] === value;
  });
  return result;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var test = findObjectByText(arr, "a", 1011);
console.log(test);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [{
      a: 1011,
      b: "abc"
    },
    {
      a: 2012,
      b: "abd"
    },
    {
      a: 2013,
      b: "cbde"
    },
    {
      a: 2014,
      b: "xyz"
    }
  ];

  function findObjectByText(arr, property, value) {
    var result = arr.filter(function(x) {
      return x[property] === value;
    });
    return result;
  }
  var test = findObjectByText(arr, "a", 1011);
  console.log(test);
}());
```

**Update:** Using a generic function.

```
function search(arr, value) {
  for (var i in arr) {
    for (var j in arr[i]) {
      if (arr[i][j] === value) {
        return arr[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [{
      a: 1011,
      b: "abc"
    },
    {
      a: 2012,
      b: "abd"
    },
    {
      a: 2013,
      b: "cbde"
    },
    {
      a: 2014,
      b: "xyz"
    }
  ];


  function search(arr, value) {
    for (var i in arr) {
      for (var j in arr[i]) {
        if (arr[i][j] === value) {
          return arr[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  var test = search(arr, 1011);
  console.log(test);
}());
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without passing property name . Also my another issue is it's not equality check , it's contains . It should be able to handle all datatypes ie search on numbers , strings  etc.

Comment: @SatyaSahoo Yes, I've updated my answer with a new example.